# Amplitude decrease in FFT at higher frequency for multisine

Tags: fft, frequency, amplitude

I am adding sine signals with different frequencies but same amplitude=100.
Sampling frequency is  50MHz.

I am not getting 100 in frequency domain for frequency 787KHz.

At 1K, 3K I am getting 100 amplitude,
but at 787KHz I am getting 75.9 .
All the signals have 100 V amplitude.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Can you plot this result and provide more specifics on what you are doing for the FFT: Total number of samples? Are you zero-padding or windowing? Were any other signals added as well?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a result of [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage), it can be mitigated by using multitone frequencies that are [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ACoherent_sampling) with the sampling frequency.
There is a nice [tutorial](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/apn/an9675-tutorial-coherent-and-windowed-sampling-ad-converters?language=en?language=en) about coherent sampling from Renesas.

Comment: If I compute FFT of the same sample of data in "C language environment IDE(like eclipse)"   I am getting amplitude of 100 for every frequencies in frequency domain. Why do I get this difference ?

Comment: OK, do you use exactly the same number of data and sample rate as you have in Matlab?

Comment: Yes . Exactly the same data.

Comment: Strange, then it probably differs in the implementation or windowing functions. Hard to tell without seeing the code ...

Comment: There was a mistake in C  code itself